# Sorting list by date then letter

Tags: excel, list, sorting

How can I sort a list by date then letter (preferably without using VBA)? Every time I mess with the sort options it sorts by number first. Do I need to write some kind of sorter? Is there a Google search I'm not doing? For example:

```
1884-S
1885-P
1884-O
```

should return:

```
1884-O
1884-S
1885-P
```

Comment: Is there any chance of having the date and the letter in two separate columns?

Comment: As Vinnie suggested, in a new column type the formula `=RIGHT(a2, 1)`. a2 should be changed to whatever cell reference your numbers are in. 1 means return the first character from the right (i.e. the last character). Drag the formula down to cover all of your data. This will give you a new column with just the letter in. You can then sort by that column A-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use right() (or left(), mid() if you have different text) to have the letters in a different column and sort the data based on that column.